exploded jar can't find managed Bean
I've been running my SpringBoot (3) WebApp fine using the embedded tomcat with `mvn spring-boot:run'
Now I'm trying to run the App from the /target directory using a startup script that puts all the libs from WEB-INF/lib, as well as all the class files from WEB-INF/classes onto the class path, then calling the Application main class.
At startup, I get the following output:
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.5)

2024-05-27T19:07:15,511 INFO  [main] o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger: Starting Application using Java 17.0.9 with PID 51388 (/Users/george/projects/myapp/target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes started by george in /Users/george/projects/myapp/target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
2024-05-27T19:07:15,514 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger: Running with Spring Boot v3.1.5, Spring v6.0.13
2024-05-27T19:07:15,515 INFO  [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-27T19:07:16,595 INFO  [main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2024-05-27T19:07:16,603 INFO  [main] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
2024-05-27T19:07:16,605 INFO  [main] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-27T19:07:16,606 INFO  [main] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2024-05-27T19:07:16,725 INFO  [main] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-27T19:07:16,726 INFO  [main] o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1172 ms
Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
2024-05-27T19:07:16,731 INFO  [main] c.e.c.SessionListenerWithMetrics: SessionListenerWithMetrics
2024-05-27T19:07:16,783 WARN  [main] o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authSuccessHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'projectAclService': Error creating bean with name 'projectAclService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'projectAclRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'com.company.myapp.repository.ProjectAclRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2024-05-27T19:07:16,786 INFO  [main] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-05-27T19:07:16,800 INFO  [main] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger: 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-27T19:07:16,816 ERROR [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field projectAclRepository in com.company.myapp.service.ProjectAclService required a bean of type 'com.company.myapp.repository.ProjectAclRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.myapp.repository.ProjectAclRepository' in your configuration.

My Application classes must be on the classpath, or the App wouldn't even start;
I have:
java -cp ./WEB-INF/classes:HikariCP-5.0.1.jar...
what could be missing from the classpath to cause this issue?

Don't. Build the jar and just run java -jar your-jar.jar. No need to make it more complicated then that.

I want to run an exploded war for reasons.  I know it's possible

You still need to use the spring boot generated jar and extract it, don't use the intermediate stuff in the target directory. Next to that you would need a specific launcher and not just run a java command with additional classpath properties. But why do you want to run the exploded jar, generally you wouldn't need to do and it will only complicate things.

could you elaborate on what you mean by a 'specific launcher'?  what is needed other than the correct classpath?

Please add the full command you use to launch the application, also as stated don't use the intermediate steps. Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/deployment/efficient.html#deployment.efficient.unpacking for some info. Next to that I would really be curious as to why you think you must extract and run it like this. Generally there are better ways to achieve results then this. Finally why are you building a WAR file (which is for deployment to a tomcat server) instead of a JAR file, you are running it from the commandline anyway, there is no benefit from packaging it as a WAR.

Working now.  By running from an exploded jar I was able to modify certain files 'in situ' where they were deployed, to examine the effects of changes on my hosted instance, without having to deploy a new Docker image with each line change.  I won't be using this method in Prod.

Then just run the application from your IDE, enable dev tools and have hot reloading do the work for you.

I'm running the App in a Docker container on my hosted server.. there's no IDE

I was able to get this running by creating a jar containing com.company.myapp classes (i.e. myapp.jar), and including it along with the other jar files from WEB-INF/lib.
Presumably this has an implicit effect on the Classloader.
